# ASP.NET, Session maintaining on pageload and postback

Tags: asp.net, session, pageload

I am making a website where I need to maintain a session of logged in User. There are different pages so have to maintain the session for each page. I am passing the value in my session variable on click event of enter button on home page.
The code works fine for the first time, but when user redirects from another page to home page the session gets null. I am confused where to make the session so as to retain the value for all of the pages.?

Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Session["UserName"] = null;
    //Session["UserRoles"] = null;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) //if page is not postback then here
    {
        Session["UserName"] = null;
        Session["UserRoles"] = null;
        if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"] == "Admin")
        {
            divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
            lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"] + "(Admin)";
        }
        else if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"] == "member")
        {
            divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
            lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"];
        }
    }

    else //if page postback then here
    {
        if (Session["UserRoles"] != null)
        {
            if ((String)Session["UserRoles"]=="Admin")
            {
                divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
                lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"] + "(Admin)";
            }
            else
            {
                divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
                lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"];
            }
        }
    }


}


 protected void btnenter_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session["UserName"] = null;
            Session["UserRoles"] = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt=getUserInfo(txtUserId.Text.Trim(),txtPassword.Text.Trim());

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script> alert('User Not Exist')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                strUserName = dt.Rows[0]["User_Name"].ToString();
               // strUserName = txtUserId.Text.Trim(); 
                struserRoles = dt.Rows[0]["USER_ROLE"].ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = (String)strUserName;
                Session["UserRoles"] = (String)struserRoles;

                if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"]=="Admin")
                {
                    divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
                    lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"] + "(Admin)";
                }
                else if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"] == "Member")
                {
                    divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
                    lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"];
                }
                Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx", false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Based on your question, I'm not quite sure you understand how session behavior works in ASP.NET. You shouldn't have to do anything to persist session between pages in the same website.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for your reply,
I am a begineer in ASP.Net so I request you to be easy on me, but I know that sessions are maintained in ASP.Net, actually I need to know where exactly should I put the check on my session variables so as to differentiate between Admin or Member users and also to maintain that session value?

Comment: Not a problem! Actually, I think the answer from @Hussein Roncevic is very well taken - ASP.NET has facilities to manage much of this kind of housekeeping for you, and it will make your code much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

The problem that you have is that in the first `if` part when you check for PostBack, you are clearing the Session variables and then check them for null. There is no point here. They will always be null and your `if` and `else if` will never happen. Rethink your strategy and what you want to achieve.

Now, my comments regarding what you are trying to do...  First of all, using Session in this manner is a sort of thing that you would have done in Classic ASP. With ASP.NET there are far better mechanisms to do this. Instead, you should leverage `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` to authenticate your users and to keep track of them. Instead of reading username from a session variable you would normally use `Page.User.Identity.Name` to retrieve user's ID or username. In addition to this you can use `Roles.IsUserInRole()` or some other static method in the `Roles` class.

Second thing, you are repeating your variable names too many times. That is, you are using hard coded strings which point to the same thing in too many places. Your maintenance is going to be a mess. While you are still early in the development phase, switch to `FormsAuthentication` to have ASP.NET handle all the above tasks for you.

UPDATE: ASP.NET contains a set of components regarding login and security. One of these is `LoginView` which allows to specify different views based on different roles. By using this control you don't have to bother with the checks that you are conducting.

The check that you do is OK in Page_Load, but you really need to optimize this. If it is necessary to have a constant check then don't bother with `if (IsPostBack) ... else ...`. Do this check outside. For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && Session["UserRoles"] == "Admin")
    {
        // Show Admin section
        // Hide Non-admin section
    }
    else
    {
        // Hide Admin section
        // Show non-admin section
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do Postback logic here
    }
}
```

Again, what you are trying to achieve is already available as `LoginView` component. Have a look at these [Web Forms tutorials on ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security)

Comment: Thanks Husein for your reply,

Comment: Thanks Husein for your reply, actually I need to maintain the session one for admin and another for members and on the basis of these roles I need to display/hide some of the elements, so that is why I am making the sessions and maintaining them. And yes I got that point for assigning the null value in the first if statement. Can you please tell me where exactly to use this session so as to check whether logged in user is Admin or member?? 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I'm not quite sure you understand how session behavior works in ASP.NET. You shouldn't have to do anything to persist session between pages in the same website. Additionally, the code snippet you provided will never do anything:

```
       // You set theses two session vars to null, but then 
       // immediately check for contents??
       Session["UserName"] = null;
        Session["UserRoles"] = null;

        // Neither of these if statements will ever evaluate to true,
        // because you just set them to null above..
        if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"] == "Admin")
        {
            divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
            lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"] + "(Admin)";
        }
        else if (Session["UserRoles"] != null && (String)Session["UserRoles"] == "member")
        {
            divLoggedInMember.Visible = true;
            lblLoggedinUser.Text = "Welcome" + " " + Session["UserName"];
        }
```